# CentOS 7 (1708) offline yum update

Tags: centos, yum, zabbix

I must start a Zabbix server on CentOS, but first I need to configure and prepare CentOS for it. I've installed a totally new CentOS and now must update it via `yum update`, but there is a problem. There is no internet link to the server, so I suppose I should do it in offline mode?

I've found, that `yum update` means update of RPMS and repodata, which can be found here: http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7.4.1708/

How can I do it using a simple flash disk (usb)?

Should I download each of the files from that mirror in the `/updates` directory, place them to exact folder (like in mirror) and then install? If so, in which order should I do it? What to install first, second, and so on?

Comment: You said "so I suppose I should do it in offline mode" - I'd suggest confirming that first. If you can sort out the connectivity (fix config, use a proxy - whatever), your biggest problem goes away.

Comment: I suppose in this situation = I must. There is no way to connect anything except usb flash disk atm.

Answer (score 1):

You can configure either a [local based repository](https://blog.fpmurphy.com/2017/01/configure-a-local-iso-based-package-repository-on-a-centos-7-2-vm.html) or a [host-base repository](https://blog.fpmurphy.com/2017/02/configure-a-host-iso-based-package-repository-on-a-centos-7-2-vm.html).  While the example configurations provided in my blog are for VMs, the same general ideas apply.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no way. Server is a standalone hardware in the rack and boss wants me to configure it, so when the link will be available, we'll be able to "plug and play" with Zabbix monitoring with pre-configured server.

Comment: Well, why did you not say that in the first place!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by setting up a local repository using the instalattion media. After that, in the zabbix page you can download the packets you need to install zabbix in a very basic way.

Remember that you can install RPM files locally by using

```
yum localinstall <package.rpm>
```